# Kaspersky Internet Security. Внедрение в другие процессы

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, kaspersky

В Kaspersky Internet Security есть возможность ограничивать функционал конкретных приложений через меню "Управление программами" -> "Подробности и правила" -> "Права".

Один из блоков - "Внедрение в другие процессы".
Т.о. антивирус может запретить приложению внедряться и читать/писать память других процессов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, **как это реализовано** с технической точки зрения? У меня есть необходимость реализовать подобный функционал в моем приложении.

Например запрет на чтение памяти других процессов, я себе представляю следующим образом:

DLL Injection в целевое приложение -> Хук на ReadProcessMemory -> Замена своей функцией, которая будет давать отказ.

**Так ли это работает в антивирусе?**

Comment: Кернелмод там наверняка используется.